# Rewriting this frankenstein promise chain

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, bluebird

So i brought to life this abomination and i couldnt for the life of me get my head around how to optimise it in such a way i can run this chain properly using Promise.all / Promise.join.

Anyone able to point me in the right direction? Should probably separate the methods first.

Any insight is appreciated.

```js
getOpenIDConf: function() {
  return client
    .getAsync('openId')
    .then(
      function(result) {
        if (!result) {
          return request
            .getAsync({
              url: 'https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration',
              json: true
            }).spread(
              function(response, body) {
                var result = JSON
                  .stringify(body);
                client.setAsync('openId',
                  result).then(
                  function() {
                    return result;
                  });
              });
        } else {
          return result;
        }
      });

},
```

[EDIT] To clarify, i'm using bluebird

Comment: Does that actually work? You should never be able to return the result of a promise. You can only return the promise itself.

Comment: I seem to be getting my result just fine

Comment: Did you mean to return `client.setAsync(...` inside the `spread` callback?

Comment: Then it's really weird. The only way that return works is if the function isn't async. Async function can only get results from callbacks. In the case of promises you return the promise which will allow you to pass a callback to the `.then()` method. You can never return results from async functions. You can only get them from callbacks regardless weather you use a promise or regular callback.

Comment: @slebetman I'm guessing he hasn't tested the `!result` case yet

Comment: @acbabis: In the `else` case he's returning a result. Which would return it to the event loop instead of the code calling the `getOpenIDConf.then()` method.

Comment: You guys are right, got undefined back after clearing redis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refactoring a bit and changing the code style gives this.

```js
getOpenIDConf: () => client.getAsync('openId').then(result =>
    result || request.getAsync({
      url: 'https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration',
      json: true
    }).get(1).then(JSON.stringify).then(result =>
      client.setAsync('openId', result).return(result);
    )
  )
},
```

Comment: So other then the if/else, the code is 'alright' in terms of cleanliness? Was mainly concerned about (ab)using Promises incorrectly.

Comment: @KevinToet Actually, the if/else is also a matter of preference. You didn't abuse Promises, IMO. Promise abuse is nesting lots of callbacks when you don't have to.

Comment: What's that lambda annotation you use? Eclipse is throwing a fit. Could you also explain the get(1) ?

Comment: @KevinToet [get](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/get.html) returns a promise that resolves with the specified parameter from the previous promise. Since you only wanted `body`, using `get` saved you a `spread`. The [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) are a new ES6 feature available in node [4.0](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v4.0.0/). If you're using Node 0.12, you will have to use regular functions instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for the thoroughness

Answer (score 1):

A few features of a good promise library (not sure which one you are using) is that you can chain the promises like so:

```
doSomething(function(result) {
  return doSomethingElse();
}).then(function(result2) {
  return doSomethingElseAgain();
}).then(function(result3) {
  // It all worked!
}).catch(function() {
  // Something went wrong
});
```

Or you can wait for a set of them to complete:

```
var promiseArray = [];
promiseArray.push(doSomething());
promiseArray.push(doSomethingElse());
promiseArray.push(doSomethingElseAgain());

Promise.all(promiseArray).then(function() {
  // It all worked!
}).catch(function() {
  // Something went wrong
});
```

Hope this is informative.